# right way of weighting sampling for a distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

Recently I have read a [paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lsong/papers/DuFarAhmSmoSon15.pdf), in a part of that the authors try to sample from the distribution $p(\alpha|\tau )=P(\tau | \alpha)\times p(\alpha | \alpha_0)$ where $\tau$ is some evidences in the problem.
They propose to generate $N$ samples from the prior, $p(\alpha | \alpha_0)$, call them $\left \{ \alpha^{i} \right \}_{i=1,...,N}$ and then estimate the posterior $\alpha$ using this formula:
$$
\hat{\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_i\alpha^{i}
$$
where:
$$
w_i=\frac{p(\tau|\alpha^{i})P(\alpha^i|\alpha_0)}{\sum_i p(\tau|\alpha^{i})P(\alpha^i|\alpha_0)}
$$

I am skeptical of their method. actually I think that their weighting schema is wrong because they double count the weakness of samples by importing $P(\alpha^i|\alpha_0)$ in their weight calculation.Actually I think that the weight calculation should be :
$$
w_i=\frac{p(\tau|\alpha^{i})}{\sum_i p(\tau|\alpha^{i})}
$$

I would be apperciated if give me some hints of what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: I corrected one spot of grammar, but I think you also have a typo in the math.  In your first sentence, I think you must mean to have $p(\tau\mid\alpha)$ in on the left side of the equals sign.  That seems to be the only thing that makes sense in context.

Comment: @Brick: No, I think it's correctly quoted this way around; see p. $6$ of the PDF, top left.

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: In the future, when you provide a link (which is great), please also provide a page / equation / section number so that people don't have to go searching.

Comment: @joriki, OK, so I agree that the order of the arguments is copied faithfully from the source provided, but they don't claim equality in the original. (They use the ~ symbol instead, indicating something less than equality.) I'm not able to make sense of what they are saying - The claim that this follows from Bayes law appears wrong to me. Maybe a full reading of the paper would clarify it, but that's beyond the scope of the help that I'm able to provide here.

Comment: @joriki yes, You are right I should provide the reference too. thanks.

Comment: I think there was an answer here which is deleted now. unfortunately I didn't read it.

Comment: The answer basically said that the weights are correct. It was deleted after I added this comment under it: "The weight is correct for uniformly drawn samples. The OP's point is that part of the weight is already taken into account when sampling from the prior instead of sampling uniformly, and this part shouldn't be repeated in the weights."

Comment: yes, Thank you a lot.@joriki